# Large Message in web socket taking absurdly long

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, socket.io

In my current app, I transmit a large string (approximately 0.4MB) every few milliseconds. When I transmit this text from the server, I make the following blocking call.

```
data = websocket.recv()
```

I've found that this step takes a VERY long time.

As I am new to socket programming, forgive me if I'm ignorant. Are web sockets not able to handle 0.4MB?  **How can I speed this up?** I've noticed that when I decrease the size of the text, the speed of my program increases significantly. I've read in places that websockets can handle up to 4MB in message size, but my experiments do not bode well (it takes MUCH MUCH longer).

One thing I've been thinking about is to have the client websocket in another thread. This way it doesn't block the call. But I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: What you could do is reduce the chunck of data that is being sent over the client, or adjust it to better fit your need.

Comment: Good point. The issue is that I've already compressed it and it works out to be 0.4MB. Maybe another idea is to transmit a "delta" of the data.

Comment: It can't go any faster than it takes for the data to traverse the network. Do you have any evidence that it's taking longer than that?

Comment: Maybe websocket.recv() is trying to build your message. There is a concept called continuation frames in WebSocket that you can use to get messages in chunks to speed up your application: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 Not sure how it is handled in python